# Entering local admin username and password in a script

Tags: windows, scripting, automation, windows-command-prompt, uac

I have alot of clients on my network and I want my script to do the following:

[1] Open an elevated command prompt using the local admin details. 
    Note: I do not want to have to enter a username and password for each user.

[2] Uninstall java using the following command:
    "wmic product where "name like 'java%'" call uninstall"

[3] I then want to install another version of Java once the PC reboots.

I'm not too worried about steps 2 and 3 at the moment, however step 1 is causing me some problems. I have tried the methods below:

**runas command

NirSoft programs

PowerShell**

I'm really just wondering if this is possible without going around to every PC on the network and entering the local admin password.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098101/how-to-open-an-elevated-cmd-using-command-line-for-windows

Thanks in advance.
Timbo

Comment: http://www.urtech.ca/2011/05/how-to-deploy-oraclesun-java-silently-in-a-corporate-environment-with-group-policy-in-active-directory-or-using-a-script/

Comment: If you are asking if you can bypass the UAC prompt from script, the answer is of course "no." (If it were possible, all malware would do it.)

Answer (score 11):

Start your batch:

```
powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs"
...
rest of script
...
```

This will open an elevated command prompt

Keep in mind for this to work the user would need to have admin privilege on the box.

If the user is not a local admin you will have the use the /savecred switch, this is a big security hole as then the user and can use the /savecred switch on anything else they want.

If you have AD you can always do this through GPO.

Comment: Thanks for the response what I'm really looking for is a way to enter in the admin details in a script without having to manually enter them on each PC.